# CSS counter effect

Tags: html, css

On twitter, when a tweet gains likes/retweets theres a neat animation for the number going up. I found a similar effect for CSS but it uses a really strange method:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:after {
  content: attr(data-val);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: loop 10s linear;
  animation: loop 10s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% { margin-top: 0px; }
  9% { margin-top: 0px; }
  10% { margin-top: -20px; }
  19% { margin-top: -20px; }
  20% { margin-top: -40px; }
  29% { margin-top: -40px; }
  30% { margin-top: -60px; }
  39% { margin-top: -60px; }
  40% { margin-top: -80px; }
  49% { margin-top: -80px; }
  50% { margin-top: -100px; }
  59% { margin-top: -100px; }
  60% { margin-top: -120px; }
  69% { margin-top: -120px; }
  70% { margin-top: -140px; }
  79% { margin-top: -140px; }
  80% { margin-top: -160px; }
  89% { margin-top: -160px; }
  90% { margin-top: -180px; }
  99% { margin-top: -180px; }
  100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
@keyframes loop {
  0% { margin-top: 0px; }
  9% { margin-top: 0px; }
  10% { margin-top: -20px; }
  19% { margin-top: -20px; }
  20% { margin-top: -40px; }
  29% { margin-top: -40px; }
  30% { margin-top: -60px; }
  39% { margin-top: -60px; }
  40% { margin-top: -80px; }
  49% { margin-top: -80px; }
  50% { margin-top: -100px; }
  59% { margin-top: -100px; }
  60% { margin-top: -120px; }
  69% { margin-top: -120px; }
  70% { margin-top: -140px; }
  79% { margin-top: -140px; }
  80% { margin-top: -160px; }
  89% { margin-top: -160px; }
  90% { margin-top: -180px; }
  99% { margin-top: -180px; }
  100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="loop" data-val="0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90"></div>
```

This method is really difficult to incorporate into my project. I was wondering if anyone knew a better solution for something where I don't necessarily know what the added number will be...

```js
$('.add').on("click", function() {
  
  
  let numb = $('.numb');
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  
  numb.text(parseInt(numb.text()) + rand)

});
```

```css
.numb {
 padding: 12px 0;
 font-size: 26px;
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numb">5</div>
<button class="add">Add to number</button>
```

Would anyone know a good alternative to create the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect is possible by toggling a class, what i did is use translateY to make the last number always visible, when i add another div, switch to another class that makes the second last number visible, then remove that class.

```js
function createNum() {
    let numb = document.querySelector(".numb_list");
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    let newNum = document.createElement("div");
    newNum.innerText = rand;
    numb.classList.toggle("switch");
    numb.appendChild(newNum);
    setTimeout(function() {
     numb.classList.toggle("switch");
    },1)
  }
```

```css
.numb_container {
 height: 21px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.numb_list {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 21px));
    transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.switch {
 transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 42px));
 transition: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="numb_container">
 <div class="numb_list">
  <div>1</div>
 </div>
</div>
<button class="add" onclick="createNum()">Add to number</button>
```